# Is there a way to allow a user to change it's own password on Hashicorp's Vault UI

Tags: authentication, settings, hashicorp-vault, change-password

I wanted to let users change their own password within HashiCorp's Vault (assuming, we're using userpass auth).

I don't find any way to do so. Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [this](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/policy-templating) link has your answer.

It would look something like this

```
path "auth/userpass/users/{{identity.entity.aliases.auth_userpass_6671d643.name}}" {
  capabilities = [ "update" ]
  allowed_parameters = {
    "password" = []
  }
}
```

where `auth_userpass_6671d643` is the mount of your userpass authentication and can be retrieved via `vault auth list` command.

Comment: I've came across something similar to this. Sadly it doesn't allow for users to change their password inside the vault web UI.

Comment: all bets are off for the GUI - i havent touched that

Comment: Accepted the answer. But only works for the CLI / REST API

Comment: You can read the mount accessor via `vault auth list` (not `vault secrets list`)

Answer (score 0):

To make it possible to not create different policy for each user, it might be handy to use next policy:

```
path "auth/userpass/users/{{identity.entity.name}}" {
  capabilities = [ "update" ]
  allowed_parameters = {
    "password" = []
  }
}
```

It also requires admins to change entity names for each user to be equal to the username (lower-cased), but it looks more handy then another solutions.